# Append to json file with Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

my angular app produces an array like this:

```
arrayToAppend = ["Channel", "Taco", "Taco", "", "La", "male", "0", "81.6", "fd", "fd", "fd", "fd", "0", "ci.png", "cis", "1", "", "", "20160204_145319"]
```

and I would like to append this array to a jsonp file that already exists on the same server. The path of the file is:

```
../../app/db.jsonp
```

and it looks like this:

```
callback([
    ["brand" , "model"     , "modelStrict"     , "modelSpec"     , "name"    , "gender" , "size"  , "weight" , "length"   , "width"     , "thick"    , "volume" , "fun" , "imageName"      , "photocredits"   , "pertinence" , "year" , "winning", "timestamp"]       ,
    ["Channel", "Taco", "Taco", "", "La", "male", "0", "81.6", "fd", "fd", "fd", "fd", "0", "ci.png", "cis", "1", "", "", "20160204_145319"],
    ["Channel", "Taco", "Taco", "", "La", "male", "0", "81.6", "fd", "fd", "fd", "fd", "0", "ci.png", "cis", "1", "", "", "20160204_145319"],
    ["Channel", "Taco", "Taco", "", "La", "male", "0", "81.6", "fd", "fd", "fd", "fd", "0", "ci.png", "cis", "1", "", "", "20160204_145319"],
    ["Channel", "Taco", "Taco", "", "La", "male", "0", "81.6", "fd", "fd", "fd", "fd", "0", "ci.png", "cis", "1", "", "", "20160204_145319"]
]);
```

Can you help me achieve this please ?

Thanks

Comment: You need a server application to edit the file. You can't do it with client side (angular).

Comment: You need to post this to the server - look at the angular $http module. You haven't given any hint as to what server side technology you are using to save the file.

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant Can you please show me some code to send this array to the server and some php code to append to the existing file ?

Comment: @LeeWillis server side I am just using php

Comment: you need to append remotely or locally? if you need this on php, it isn't a angularjs question...

Comment: @JoaozitoPolo I need to append to a file that is on the server

Comment: on php... store the array in a var, append then, and returns the var

Comment: @JoaozitoPolo yeah I am a newbie :) can you show some code ?

Comment: I refer to this function: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_push.asp

Comment: Hey everyone, thanks for putting me on the right track, can you update my answer below to make it work well ?  I need to add the "callback" in the newly created jsonp file using php, how can I do this ?

Comment: @JoaozitoPolo can you check if the solution seems good ?

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant can you check if the solution seems good ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I am attempting my own answer, can you please edit to help make it good ?

service.js:

```
.service('sendToServer', [
        '$http',
        function ($http) {
            'use strict';

            this.f = function (dataToSend) {
                return $http({
                    url: 'http://login:pwd@boardl.com/app/appendToDb.php',
                    method: "POST",
                    data: dataToSend
                });
            };
        }
    ])
```

controller.js:

```
 sendToServer.f(array).success(handleSuccess).error(handleError);
```

appendToDb.php on the server:

```
<?php
//header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");

if($_POST) {
  $data[] = $_POST['data'];
  $inp = file_get_contents('../../app/db.jsonp');
  $tempArray = json_decode($inp, true);
  array_push($tempArray, $data);
  $jsonData = json_encode($tempArray);
  file_put_contents('results.json', $jsonData);
}
?>
```

Comment: I think it's a cool solution... but it needs an intervention at PHP. If you already had the data to append at angularjs, AND the server not will to store the data... you can simply add after angularjs $http success.

Comment: I don't understand, can you show some code please ?

Comment: is the application under the same domain ? if not, you need to allow method OPTIONS too, and to use `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");`

Comment: second point: json_decode($inp); is wrong, you have to use json_decode($inp, true); if you want an array

Comment: Thanks, the applicatoin is under the same domain. I change the json_decode line thanks. But I can't even get my $_POST data, printing `file_put_contents('../../app/db.jsonp', print_r($_POST, true), FILE_APPEND);` gives an empty array ! Can you help me with this code ?

Comment: should I serialize or something ? because of the json format and the format of my array ?